# How to integrate Citrus payment gateway without asking for login to user in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, citrus-pay

Hope you are doing well.

I am trying to integrate CitrusPay SDK to my iPhone application. How can i integrate CitrusPay Direct payment without asking user to login to citrus pay.

I want to give options to user like :

1. Pay using Citrus Wallet
2. Pay using Creditcard/Debit Card
3. Pay using Net banking

If user would like to pay using Citrus Wallet then i will ask user to login to citrus using their credentials. If they will go with 2nd or 3rd option like pay using Credit Card/Debit Card or net banking then they don't need to login.

I want to implement this function in my app using CitrusPay SDK. Can you point out me for the code of this?

I already have a demo of the Citrus pay and i already checked it.

https://github.com/citruspay/citruspay-ios-sdk

I downloaded the demo from the above link.

Please help me out for this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this SDK, but I assume that at certain point in the code you instantiate an object that takes care of the service and pass it the credentials (user name and password), and perhaps the sample code assumes the credentials are hard-coded and authenticates right away on app launch. You need to move that SDK-initializing code to the point in your app where you want the user to login.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [CitrusPaymentSDK enableDEBUGLogs];

    CTSKeyStore *keyStore = [[CTSKeyStore alloc] init];
    keyStore.signinId = SignInId;
    keyStore.signinSecret = SignInSecretKey;
    keyStore.signUpId = SubscriptionId;
    keyStore.signUpSecret = SubscriptionSecretKey;
    keyStore.vanity = VanityUrl;

    [CitrusPaymentSDK initializeWithKeyStore:keyStore environment:CTSEnvSandbox];

    [CitrusPaymentSDK enableDEBUGLogs];

    //CC, DC payments
    CTSElectronicCardUpdate *creditCard = [[CTSElectronicCardUpdate alloc] initCreditCard]; //for debit card use > initDebitCard
    creditCard.number = @"";
    creditCard.expiryDate = @"XX/XX"; //only mm/yyyy format
    creditCard.scheme = [CTSUtility fetchCardSchemeForCardNumber:creditCard.number]; //fetch card scheme
    creditCard.ownerName = @"XXXXXXXX"; // no special characters here
    creditCard.cvv = @"XXX";


    CTSPaymentLayer *paymentLayer = [CitrusPaymentSDK fetchSharedPaymentLayer];

    CTSPaymentDetailUpdate *paymentInfo = [[CTSPaymentDetailUpdate alloc] init];
    [paymentInfo addCard:creditCard];

    CTSContactUpdate* contactInfo;
    CTSUserAddress* addressInfo;

    contactInfo = [[CTSContactUpdate alloc] init];
    contactInfo.firstName = @"";
    contactInfo.lastName = @"";
    contactInfo.email = @"";
    contactInfo.mobile = @"";

    addressInfo = [[CTSUserAddress alloc] init];
    addressInfo.city = TEST_CITY;
    addressInfo.country = TEST_COUNTRY;
    addressInfo.state = TEST_STATE;
    addressInfo.street1 = TEST_STREET1;
    addressInfo.street2 = TEST_STREET2;
    addressInfo.zip = TEST_ZIP;


    [CTSUtility requestBillAmount:@"X" billURL:BillUrl callback: ^(CTSBill *bill , NSError *error){

        if(error){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            });
            [UIUtility toastMessageOnScreen:error.localizedDescription];
        }
        else {
            [paymentLayer requestDirectChargePayment:paymentInfo withContact:contactInfo withAddress:addressInfo bill:bill returnViewController:self withCompletionHandler:^(CTSCitrusCashRes *citrusCashResponse, NSError *error){

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //                                    [self.indicatorView stopAnimating];
                    //                                    self.indicatorView.hidden = TRUE;
                });
                if(error){
                    [UIUtility toastMessageOnScreen:error.localizedDescription];
                }
                else {
                    [UIUtility toastMessageOnScreen:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Payment Status %@",[citrusCashResponse.responseDict valueForKey:@"TxStatus"] ]];
                    //                                    [self resetUI];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
```